# Host Git in TFS without using ALM

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, tfs

Is there any benefit at all in using TFS to host a git repo if we don't plan to use the TFS ALM features (like work items, scrum tools, etc)?

We use Jira for ALM, and we use Jenkins for builds, so really, we will only be using TFS for source control.  We are moving from SVN to either TFS (TFSVC) or GIT for source control.

Does the Microsoft Git source control provider work any differently if you are using TFS-hosted git vs. hosting git natively in Apache (or, more likely for us, hosted in Bonobo's windows git server)?

**Edit**

Hi all -- just adding some clarification here -- what I'm really looking for is to know whether the Visual Studio tooling for git behaves differently when you use TFS to manage the central repo vs. git over https without tfs.

Comment: Hello all:  I see a couple of votes to close on this question.  I would like to rephrase it in a way that is acceptable.  Can anyone comment as to why the close vote?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Git provided inside of TFS (I recommend that you use VSO) is truly enterprise ready. With the ability to turn of rewriting history at the administrative level you get better control.

On top of that you get AD or AAD integration that gives audit capabilities. While users can make up their identity for commit, a push is auditable.

Comment: Any word on SSH support? If not, it's not enterprise ready and I wouldn't recommend until it does.  This has been 2 years now: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/3801342-add-support-for-ssh-keys-as-alternate-authenticati

Comment: Let me put it another way... I'm a Microsoft / Windows centralized DevOps professional with 20 years on the platform and about 7 years on *nix platforms.   I treat both ecosystems as first class citizens with respect. What does TFS do now and in the future to provide auth to clients on different platforms?  Our Jenkins teams currently want to use private key private key auth over SSH and aren't interested in  storing usernames and passwords and doing HTTS connections.

Comment: Why would you use SSH instead of Kerberos?

Comment: @MrHinsh That does seem valuable.  What about the Visual Studio tooling?  are there some features that are not available if I don't use TFS to manage the git repo (bear in mind, I don't expect for the build server or work item features to be used -- just curious whether any source control related features will be different, like the merge tool, or annotations, visual tools for  checkins/branching push/pull, etc)

Comment: Ed would be better to answer that.

Comment: No, there are no source control features that depend on TFS's other capabilities.  You wouldn't get work item integration or continuous integration builds (in TFS) but source control should be complete.

Comment: @EdwardThomson you should ask that to the 1400+ people on user voice who asked for it?

Answer (score -2):

The biggest gap I see at the moment is that TFS GIT doesn't support SSH ... only HTTP/HTTPS.  Our Jenkins team won't use TFS GIT for this reason.

Comment: Someone doesn't like to be disagreed with.

Comment: Or they correctly believe it to be irrelevant to the asked question.

Comment: He asked if there was any differences between various implementations of GIT.  SSH is relevant to that question.

Comment: He did not, he asked if there were any special capabilities oF TFS Git.